# Rcpp Armadillo: how to pass an array of sparse matrices from R to Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp, kalman-filter, rcpparmadillo

I would like to write algorithms for Kalman filtering and smoothing using Rcpp Armadillo and its sparse matrix object.
If the state-space form is time-varying I have a sequence of matrices that have to be passed to Rcpp Armadillo and iterated by within Rcpp Armadillo.
The three-dimensional array is the natural object for such a problem, but I would need an array of sparse matrices (or a three-dimensional sparse array), which does not exist neither in R nor in Armadillo.

I have not figured out a smart way to pass the sequence of sparse matrices. I can only think of a list with sparse matrix elements, but I do not think it is a very efficient way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  A list of sparse matrices is your best choice.  R only interfaces to / from C with `SEXP` which can be mapped to a number of types, and a list (as a efficient collection of pointers) containing sparse matrices is likely your best bet.  There are a few kalman filter implmentations (including my own partially complete port in RcppKalman of a Matlab package) but I am not aware if any of these use sparse matrices.

Comment: Thanks. There are many well-written packages for Kalman filtering in R (KFAS and FKF, to mention the ones I generally use). However, I wondered if using sparse matrices would improve the performance in systems with large state vectors (and, thus, matrices). Indeed, most state-space form matrices are very sparse.
I will try your RcppKalman!

Comment: Yes that is a very valid point. But sometimes the dense matrix math implementations are so efficient that you may need a lot of sparsity to make up -- a fair question!

Comment: Just to verify if using sparse matrices is worth it, I wrote two RcppArmadillo functions to compute the Gaussian log-likelihood of a model in state-space form: one using sparse and the other using dense matrices. I applied them to two-dimensional time series of 1000 observations and a state vector with 202 variables. The transition matrix has 99% sparsity (only 400 elements of the 202 x 202 matrix are non-zero). The function with sparse matrices is 10 times faster than the dense version, which has a very similar timing as the R/KFAS function logLik.SSModel (written in Fortran).

Comment: Nice, that definitely sounds like it is worthwhile then in that model formulation you use.